# centos file creation won't work even tho 775

Tags: file, permissions, centos

we are having a problem (taht i have reproduced below on smaller scale), where we cant write a file, when i think we should

```
# ls -ld testdir
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 root 4096 Nov 19 12:13 testdir
# groups user1
user1 : user1 foo
#groups foo
foo: foo user1
```

but when i log into the foo user and from testdir start the editor

```
[foo@myhost testdir]$ nano tempfile
```

and try to save it i get  [ error writing tempfile: permission denied ] 
even tho i have 
- set the parent folder to 775
- added the user to the group that owns the folder
- relogged the foo and user1 user

(and if i change the folder to 777 it does work, but i really dont want that on the webserver (it leaves a backdoor open for hackers to replace files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group on `testdir` is `root` not `user1`.

Run `chgrp user1 testdir` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: YES!! you where right. why i didnt see that! i ran a chown user1:user1 testdir and it worked. and about the bigger picture, i made sure that the ownership of the directory on the webserver that i wanted to save files to was owned by my apache user, (cause the underlying problem was they where owned by the ftpuser with which is was created initally) chmodded it to 750 and it was fixed. thanks :)